# How to return a generator using joblib.Parallel()?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, generator, joblib

I have a piece of code below where the **`joblib.Parallel()`** returns a list.

```
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

lst = [[0.0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
arr = np.array(lst)
w, v = np.linalg.eigh(arr)

def proj_func(i):
    return np.dot(v[:,i].reshape(-1, 1), v[:,i].reshape(1, -1))

proj = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(proj_func)(i) for i in range(len(w)))
```

Instead of a list, how do I return a generator using `joblib.Parallel()`?

**Edit:**

I have updated the code as suggested by @user3666197 in comments below.

```
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

lst = [[0.0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
arr = np.array(lst)
w, v = np.linalg.eigh(arr)

def proj_func(i):
    yield np.dot(v[:,i].reshape(-1, 1), v[:,i].reshape(1, -1))

proj = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(proj_func)(i) for i in range(len(w)))
```

But I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle generator objects
```

Am I missing something? How do I fix this? My main gain here is to reduce memory as `proj` can get very large, so I would just like to call each generator in the list one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

> **Q** : *"how do I return a generator using `joblib.Parallel`?"*

Given the **`joblib`** purpose and implementation, focused on distributing code-execution units, using a set of spawned, independent processes ( yes, motivated by a boosted performance from an escape from a central GIL-lock re-`[SERIAL]`-ised dancing *one-GIL-step-after-another-GIL-step-after-...* ) made by the syntactic constructor known as **`joblib.Parallel(...)( delayed()(...) )`**, my, obviously limited imagination, tells me, the maximum achievable is but to make the ***"remotely"*** executed processes to return back to main the requested generator(s) that are `joblib`-assembled ( out of one's control ) into a list.

So an achievable maximum is to receive a **list of generators**, not any form of a deferred-execution, wrapped on return as a generator, given the above set of initial conditions and given the function **`fun()`**, set to be injected via the **`delayed( fun )(...)`** into the `joblib.Parallel( n_jobs = ... )`-many ***"remote"*-processes**, will indeed do so.

---

### A Bonus Part :

> If we were indeed pedantic purists, the only chance to receive but *"a ( one ) generator using `joblib.Parallel()`"*, for that to happen the `n_jobs` would need to be just `== 1`, which lexically and logically will meet the defined goal ***--to return (but) a (one) generator--***, yet would be less efficient and less meaningful, than throwing money into the river of Nile...

Comment: Thanks, if I am understanding what you are saying correctly what you are saying, this can be done by creating a **list of generators** using **”remote”-processes**. Is this right? If yes, how do you do this?

Comment: @Leockl Yes, you understand that correctly. **Step 1)** `def aNextNUM( aNum = 0 ): yield aNum + 1` **Step 2)** assign results returned from the `N_jobs`-many spawned `joblib.Parallel` constructor processes ( as you do above ), given the remotely-executed function simply do `return aNextNUM` a generator-object as their respective resulting value, being `joblib.Parallel()`-delivered back to the `main` caller and you are done.

Comment: Thanks @user3666197 for pointing me to the right direction on this.

Comment: Hi @user3666197, I have updated my codes as you had suggested but I am getting this error: `TypeError: can't pickle generator objects`. Can you help with what I am missing? I have updated the question.

Comment: *(Cit.) **"I have updated the question"*** - well, this is exactly what StackOverflow strongly discourages from doing. Feel free to open a new question for any new direction or on a brand new issue. Updating the original problem definition skews and creeps the focus. Do not do it again and **rather follow the Community Rules. *That's fair, isn't it?***

Comment: Ok @user3666197 apologies about this. Will keep note of this from now on.

Comment: Update: it should now be possible to get a generator to process results while the work in still ongoing and not just receive the finished list at the end. See https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/parallel_generator.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-parallel-generator-py (however it seems to be still in development according to the changelog)